# ERROR: Package 'Unidecode' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.5'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flash

ERROR: Package 'Unidecode' requires a different Python: 2.7.18 not in '>=3.5' does anyone knows what this means?

Comment: The package requires Python version 3.5 or newer while you try to install it for 2.7.18.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nothing except Python itself. Unidecode supports Python 3.5 or later.

Unfortunately Unidecode ONLY support Python 3.5 or later.

Check it in its PyPI homepage.
[Unidecode PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to install Unidecode on Python 2.7 by using an older version:

```
pip install unidecode==1.2.0
```